# custom error message codeigniter doesn't show up

Tags: codeigniter, custom-errors

the custom error message doesn't displaying the error,it only shows blank page instead error message

here is my controller :

```
public function daftar(){
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama','Nama','required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass','Password','required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf','PasswordConf','required|matches[pass]');

  if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
  $this->form_validation->set_message('passconf','the password doesnt match');

 }
 else{
   redirect('lowongan/daftar_employer');
 }

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the apostrophe in the word "doesn't".

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('passconf','the password doesn\'t match');
```

Comment: Are there any errors showing in your apache or codeigniter logs? Usually a blank page means the script has a compile error.

Comment: no errors,i already fixed the code.i put the custom error message before 'if' condition and my code works

Answer (score 0):

write a custom callback function to set your own error message

```
callback_custom_error

  $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf','PasswordConf','required|matches[pass]|callback_custom_error');


public function custom_error($str)
{
    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
    {
          $this->form_validation->set_message('passconf','your custom message');
          return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
          return TRUE;
    }

}
```

Comment: it still doesn't work,the error message still shows the default error message .